# Login to a website using Python (Simple login Form, have imacros script)

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
URL GOTO=http://www.examplesite.com/login.php
WAIT SECONDS=1.9
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:authenticate.php ATTR=ID:username1 CONTENT=MYUSERNAME
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:password FORM=ACTION:authenticate.php ATTR=ID:password1 CONTENT=MYPASSWORD
WAIT SECONDS=1.9
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:authenticate.php ATTR=ID:login&&VALUE:Login
```

This is the only thing that has worked for me with imacros extension

---

Could you help me understand how to properly convert the first part of the code into python? I've looked at various guides telling me to either use twill or beautiful soup, but they all use more complex methods.

Is there a way to directly go to ATTR=ID:username1 and tell it to input text content myusername like above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the libraries `httplib2` and `urllib` and it is easy to fill a form.

```
import httplib2, urllib
```

You have to make a dict with the form inputs as keys and its values. For example, lets try to submit a form with the input fields `name` and `email`

```
form_dict = {'name':myname, 'email':myemail}
```

Then you will do something like that:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
url = 'http://example.com/form'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(form_dict))
```